# Default user in Ubuntu fresh installation

Tags: permissions, ownership

I'm pretty new to this whole Linux and Ubuntu universe.

I've been configuring a server for development and I have run into a problem: some of the directories and files were owned by root, even though I tried to change the ownership and permissions but I had no luck.

I'm curious about how this works: is the user that you have when you install ubuntu has broad priviliges as su? If so, adding a new user would automatically change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu the *first user* or *owner of the system* is automatically added to the `sudo group` and can act like as an `sudo member`. There two ways in which you can act or *exercise sudo or root powers*, these are:

1. When you run a command that needs *sudo privileges* like say:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

   - here you will be asked for password which will be used to check if you belong to the *sudo group like the root user*, if so the command will run else it will not
2. When you switch to the *root user* with the command:

   - used when *root* account has been unlocked and here root password will be needed

     ```
     su -
     ```
   - used when *root account* has not been *unlocked* you will be asked for your password to check if you belong to *root group*

     ```
     sudo -i
     ```

Adding a new user to Ubuntu does not change that, and if you want that user to have `root powers` or `sudo powers` you will need to add the user to the `sudo group` with:

```
sudo usermod -G sudo -a user
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, George! I've been searching like crazy for a way to manage to create symlinks or change ownership but it seems really difficult between a VM and the host (my local machine). Not giving up just yet. Have a nice day!

Comment: Please could you use an example to explain your issues with the _VM and local machine_ ?

Comment: I solved it! I manually mounted my shared folder with something like this:                                                                                                                                     sudo mount.vboxsf -o umask=002,gid=33,uid=33 src /media/sf_projects                                                                                                                       Which gave me the permissions I needed in order to work with my server. Thank you for your input!